# python - erro nos parâmetros

Tags: python, django

Fiz o procedimento inicial que vi em um forum, dar nome ao app, porém não resolveu, retorna que passei 3 parâmetros e esta aguardando dois.

```py
from django.urls.conf import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),   
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning')), 
]
```

```
""" Define padrões de URL para learning_logs. """
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name="learning"

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page.
    url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

Mensagem de erro:

> 'provide the namespace argument to include() instead.' % len(arg)
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to include() is n
>   ot supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and p
>   rovide the namespace argument to include() instead.

Comment: seria interessante você [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar a versão do Django que você está usando.

Comment: provavelmente vc está errando o nome do app, verifique o nome no do app no arquivo `app.py` nas pasta de sua app

Comment: realmente era app_name = 'nome-app', estava faltando definir o namespace.